# Show that a set of logical connectives is expresively complete

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now, there doesn't seem to be ample resources online for my skill level to solve such a question:

Show that a set of connectives  {∧,¬} is expressively complete, given that {∨,∧,¬} is expressively complete.

I don't have the slightest clue how to solve this or really what it even means in context. I am very new to logic. Concepts I do understand are what the logical operators mean, and how to set up truth tables for sentence letters, and how to use truth trees for sentences.

I don't even know how to show that {∨,∧,¬} is expressively complete, let alone derive {∧,¬} . Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The term to search for is "functionally complete" or "functional completeness". That should find you lots of online references (including many MSE questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are working with propositional logic. You are given that $\{\lor, \land, \neg\}$ is expressively complete. This means that any formula in propositional logic can be rewritten so that it only uses the connectives $\lor$, $\land$, and $\neg$.

Now, to show that $\{\land, \neg\}$ is also expressively complete, all you need to do is show that you can rewrite any formula that uses only $\lor$, $\land$, and $\neg$ so that it only uses $\land$ and $\neg$, or more to the point, you need to show that you can write $\lor$ using $\land$ and $\neg$.

This can of course be done using De Morgan's laws. One of De Morgan's laws says that
$$\neg (A \lor B) \equiv \neg B \land \neg A.$$
Now, if we negate both sides of this equivalence, we get
$$\neg \neg (A \lor B) \equiv (A \lor B) \equiv \neg (\neg B \land \neg A),$$
which tells you how to write $\lor$ in terms of $\neg$ and $\land$.

Comment: So I would do something like:

(A∧B)   Apply DeMorgan's law:


-(A∨B)

Comment: @SajSeesSound Essentially yes, but you need to write $A \lor B$ with $\land$ and $\neg$, so you use the other De Morgan law.

Comment: Okay let me see if I get this. we have established that  {∨,∧,¬} (set 1) is expressively complete.  We need to show that set 2 {∧,¬} is also expressively complete. Now, set 1 and set 2 have the connectives '¬' and '∧' in common, however set 1 has '∨' but set 2 does not have ∨. We are attempting to 'get rid of' the '∨' in set 1 by converting it in to connectives only present in set 2. By doing this we prove that set two is logically equivalent?

Comment: @SajSeesSound That's correct.

Comment: I am being told that the answer should be (A or B) == -(-A and -B), How do you transform (A or B) in to the latter? DeMorgans law only applies to negations from what I know

Comment: @SajSeesSound I expanded my answer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is for the propositional language. What it means for a set of connectives to be expsively complete is that these connectives suffice to express any truth function. You don't need to show that $ \{ \lor , \land , \lnot \}$ is expressively complete---you get that for free as the hypothesis, and proceed from there that $\{ \land , \lnot \}$ is expressively complete.

**Hint**: you can convert any disjunction to a conjunction, so any formula containing a disjunction can be converted to one containing conjunction and negation only, using [De Morgan laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is show that $\lor$ can be expressed in terms of $\land$ and $\neg$. Using De Morgan, that's easy:
$$
(p\lor q) \equiv \neg(\neg p \land \neg q).
$$